# how to Access combo box of a IContributionItem

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt

I manage to add a combo box on the IToolBarManager following the code listed bellow. Now does anybody has any idea how to access the combo box that is created inside the IContributionItem from oustide that scope?

Kind Regards,
Kyriakos

```
IToolBarManager mgr = this.getViewSite().getActionBars().getToolBarManager();
IContributionItem comboCI = new ControlContribution("test") {
    protected Control createControl(Composite parent) {

        final Combo c = new Combo(parent, SWT.READ_ONLY);
        c.add("one");
        c.add("two");
        c.add("three");
        c.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
             public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                 c.add("four");
              }
              });
        return c;
    }
};        

mgr.add(comboCI);
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? You already have a listener that can be used to communicate the current value to the "outside"...

Comment: I am trying to change the values of the combo box when an other event is triggered, so I need to access the combo box outside of the scope that is declared.

Comment: The combo itself is found as the `item` member variable of the `SelectionEvent`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the combo variable inside ControlContribution class or IContributionItem interface and create a get method.

```
class ControlContribution implements IContributionItem {

    protected Combo combo;

    public Combo getCombo(){
        return combo;
    }
}
```

This way, you don't need to declare it inside the anonymous class.

```
IContributionItem comboCI = new ControlContribution("test") {
protected Control createControl(Composite parent) {

    combo = new Combo(parent, SWT.READ_ONLY);
    combo.add("one");
    combo.add("two");
    combo.add("three");
    combo.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
         public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
             combo.add("four");
          }
          });
    return combo;
}
};
```

And you can call

```
comboCI.getCombo();
```

Obviously, the IContributionItem interface need to have getCombo() method

Comment: Hi Elias and thank you for your reply. I already tried that but when I am trying to access the get method like that: levelsCombo = comboCI.getlevelsCombo(); I am getting that the get method is undefined.